# Images from url flickering with custom cursor adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, android-adapter

I am querying the SQLite database and putting the data into a List View. One of the database rows contains an image Url field (which can also be a Uri).

The images are loaded as they should but as soon as I scroll the list all the images start flickering, some are changing places or displaying in the different places.

I already understood that this behavior is happening because the List View is reusing rows on scroll, but I have no idea how to fix this behavior. Also I cannot use external libraries like Picasso in this project.

Here is my adapter code:

```
    public class FilmsListCustomAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater cursorInflater;

    public FilmsListCustomAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
        cursorInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView filmTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.filmListTitle);
        TextView filmScore = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.filmListScore);
        ImageView filmImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.filmListPoster);
        ImageView filmSeen = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.filmListSeen);

        String title = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex("title") );
        String score = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("score"));
        String url = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex("url") );
        int seen = cursor.getInt( cursor.getColumnIndex("seen") );

        if(Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches()){
            LoadImage loadImage = new LoadImage(context,filmImage);
            loadImage.execute(url);
        }
        else{
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(url);
            CamImage camImage = new CamImage(context,Uri.parse(url));
            Bitmap rotetedIm = camImage.rotateCamImage(bmp,url);
            if(rotetedIm!=null){filmImage.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(rotetedIm, 850, rotetedIm.getHeight(), false));}
            else{filmImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_poster);}
        }

        GlobalMethods methods = new GlobalMethods(context);
        filmTitle.setTypeface(methods.getWalkFont());
        filmTitle.setText(title);
        filmScore.setText(score);
        if(seen==1){filmSeen.setImageResource(R.drawable.eye);}
        else{filmSeen.setImageResource(0);}
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        return cursorInflater.inflate(R.layout.film_row, viewGroup, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to use Picasso librabry. Use Picasso or  Glide library to display image which have functionality to store image in catch, so no need to download inside list view. Here is link for Picasso : http://square.github.io/picasso/ and For Glide : https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: Its not that I don't want to. It is a school project and they demand that I wont use external libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is probably happening is this:

- You get a web URL for an image and queue an `AsyncTask` to download it for an `ImageView`
- You scroll and the `ImageView` is recycled
- This time the `ImageView` gets a local URL, so you do that immediately
- The previously queued `AsyncTask` completes and loads a now unrelated image over the image you just put in

The key to clearing this up is to make sure to cancel the task once the `ImageView` is recycled.  One way you can do this is to put a reference to the `AsyncTask` in a tag in the `ImageView`.  When you get a recycled `ImageView`, you check the tag and see if there is a task in progress and cancel it before you start a new task.

You should check out this article on Android Developers Blog, it will explain a little more about the problem and how to fix it:

[Multithreading For Performance | Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html)

I think this article was written back when `AsyncTask`s were changed to run in parallel threads, since they talk about tasks completing out of order.  They've since reverted to serial execution so I don't think that part applies anymore, but the concept is similar since your immediate loading of the local image acts like a task executing out of order.

Two other things I would consider:

- In `getView`, always call `imageView.setImageBitmap(null)` first to clear out any leftover image in the recycled `ImageView`.  I like to init `ImageView`s witth a very neutral gray bitmap that represents an "Image Loading" state.
- Use an `AsyncTask` to decode the local files as well as retrieve the web files.  I'll bet your list scrolling will seem a lot smoother when you do this.